# Django drf-spectacular with FirebaseBackend auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg, drf-spectacular

To give as much context as possible; I have two problems while using `drf-spectacular` to build my API documentation;

1. With my default configuration, I cannot even load the documentation's page because I have a custom auth backend (using `firebase_admin 5.2.0`), the swagger (or ReDoc) are part of my REST API, therefore, would have to pass a valid token to load the page allocated in the documentation's endpoint (which is not possible from a browser).
2. Second, and most importantly, I am not able to configure my custom firebase auth with `drf-spectacular` to implement a Swagger authentication method to execute against my API endpoints. I would be just fine having the possibility to add a token in the Swagger doc, do not need to have all Firebase auth credentials, URLs, and flow.

- api/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    path('api/schema/swagger/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(), name='swagger'),
    path('api/schema/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(), name='redoc'),

    # _____________________FIREBASE AUTH ______________________

    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
```

- settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'auth.backends.FirebaseBackend',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

I have unsuccessfully tried adding many different configurations to my `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS`.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By default spectacular uses `'SERVE_PERMISSIONS': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],` which should allow opening the swagger page even if not authenticated. Maybe `FirebaseBackend` bails hard which prevents you ever getting to `AllowAny`. Try this to take Firebase out of the equation for the schema views:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    ...
    'SERVE_PERMISSIONS': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny']
    'SERVE_AUTHENTICATION': [],
}
```

2. You need to write an [OpenApiAuthenticationExtension](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#specify-authentication-with-openapiauthenticationextension) for Firebase as it is not part of the spectacular at the moment.

Comment: Hi @Insa, regarding: 
1- That perfectly worked, than you! (`'SERVE_AUTHENTICATION': []`)
2- Wouldn't be possible to just configure spectacular with an Oauth token auth (or similar) and use in there the Firebase token I get from Firebase API using Postman?

Comment: 1) awesome! 2) spectacular must know what to do when it encounters `FirebaseBackend` in your View. That extension does not need to implement anything, just describe how the auth expects for this backend. That example in the link is almost complete. Just pop in your Auth class name and if you use a bearer just `return {'type': 'http','scheme': 'bearer', }`. Put that extensions somewhere in your code where it gets imported and you are done.